# Failed to load resource: Origin ionic://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: ionic-framework

ionic4 + angular8 + cordova + ios8
plugin

```
 import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

    this.http.get('http://www.xxxx.net', {})
        .subscribe(
        (res: any) => {
          log(res));
        }, error => {
          log(error);
        });
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sGos.png)
Is there any good solution? thank you

Comment: this is Server related Issue, enable `CORS` on your server and it will start working.

Comment: but can't change server

Comment: Ask the developer who worked on server.